# Remove CSS applied by a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm having trouble toggling this switch to change the background color. Im not sure how to get it to remove the CSS that it applies to the document. I want it to toggle between to different colored backgrounds.

Here's my code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <label class="switch"><input id="input" type="checkbox" /><div></div></label>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The Styles:

```
html {
background: #878476;
}

.container {
position: absolute;
top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
height: 40px;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.switch input {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
}

.switch {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 20px; /* 1 */
height: 1em;
width: 2em;
background: #BDB9A6;
border-radius: 1em;
}

.switch div {
height: 1em;
width: 1em;
border-radius: 1em;
background: #FFF;
box-shadow: 0 0.1em 0.3em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
transition: all 300ms;
transition: all 300ms;
transition: all 300ms;
}

.switch input:checked + div {
transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log( "Coffee Isn't strong enough for me to remember how to toggle the OnClick" );
$(".switch").on("click", function() {
    $("html").css("background", "blue");
});
});
```

Comment: try `addClass()` and `removeClass()`..

Comment: Use `.toggleClass()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/eLgqe2ya/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use toggle class here is link for more information http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
$("#input").on("click", function() {
    $("html").toggleClass("bck-change");
});
```

And also i've modified your code pls refer: https://jsfiddle.net/eLgqe2ya/

Comment: Why `"#input"` instead of `.switch` ?

Comment: That's because generally checkbox is the proper element to attach events to, not the label, and the change event would normally be the proper event to use, not click.